# Loop over ansible_devices and select any physical disk that is not sda for inclusion into volume group

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts

I have a requirement to build two logical volumes.  sda1 will always form /root and be partitioned up for logs and such, but /application may include anywhere from one to four additional disks.  I know they will always begin with sdb and continue on to sde or sdf.  I can think of a couple of different quick and dirty solutions like just running a bash command that builds a list to be registered as a variable, but what I would like to do instead is pull down from the ansible_devices part of Ansible setup facts and match a regex of sd[b-z].  I know it's unlikely I will ever have an sdz, but I want to keep this as flexible as possible.  Does anyone have a good technique for this? Is a jinja2 filter the wrong approach?

Comment: This is what I've come up with so far while playing around: {{ ansible_devices.keys()|difference(['sr0','sda','fd0'])|map('regex_replace','^','/dev/')|join(',') }}.  I think that's going to be the solution, but I'm open to other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select` filter with `match` test:

```
{{ ansible_devices.keys() | select('match','sd[b-c]') | list }}
```

Using `map('‌​regex_replace','^','‌​/dev/')` to prepend every string in a list is fine.